# Valet not working on kali linux. Redirecting to htdocs

Tags: linux, operating-system, kali-linux, laravel-valet

I installed valet on Kali Linux, and pinged a test domain to make sure it's working which it is. However, after running valet park in the folder directory that I have my files. It redirects me to xampp dashboard whenever I access the route on the browser. I know very well to type the folder name followed by a .test domain. I've tried almost everything online. I see this is a popular issues and I've gone through every possible solution I see online. It's still not working, I tried to rename the index.php file in the htdocs folder which gets render automatically whenever you access the htdocs folder, now it only list the folder structure for me as a result. I tried to move the project out of htdocs still not working. I stopped apache and tried accessing it again but unfortunately I got, "This site cant be reached"

Answer (score 0):

No response.. Well fortunately i was able to fix it, not sure it's the best way. But hopefully this might help someone, i configured ssl on the domain with valet using valet secure foo.bar and it automatically redirect to https. That way, i was able to escape from xampp